# Are $(\alpha ,\beta]$ and $[\alpha ,\beta)$ lebesgue measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

It is true that all open sets are lebesgue measurable, but what about not open/not close intervals?

Answer (score 3):

$$(\alpha ,\beta ]=\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\left(\alpha ,\beta +\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

So, as you can see, it's even better than just Lebesgue measurable.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**.
Every singleton is a complement of an open set, hence measurable. Therefore $(\alpha,\beta] = (\alpha,\beta)\cup\{\beta\}$ is a union of two measurable sets.

Comment: a bit off topic, but if a singleton is measurable, then we can say that for any $f$ the set $f^{-1}({a})$ is measurable therefore $f$ is measurable?

Comment: @gbox the other way around. If $f$ is measurable then $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is measurable. However even if $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is measurable for all $a$ it may not be the case that $f$ is measurable (unless the range is countable).